# Mostrar datos de un Jlist

Tags: java

tengo un jList con items(Estos items son id de una tabla SQL,Ver Imagen) Lo que pretendo hacer que cada vez que pulse a un item del Jlist salga el nombre del Id(sentencia SQL) en un jtextfield. Pero Cada vez que pulse a un elemento del jlist me salta un error.Seguro que es una chorrada pero no consigo solucionarlo :)

Imagen
[image: Jlist items]

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class prueba.Cancion. Expected: class prueba.Cancion, got class java.lang.Integer
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.checkIdClass(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:166)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:86)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1239)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1900(SessionImpl.java:203)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2804)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2778)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1075)
at prueba.Principal.rellenarValoresLista(Principal.java:46)
at prueba.Principal.valueChanged(Principal.java:178)
at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1796)
at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1810)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:164)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:211)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:405)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:415)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setSelectionInterval(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:459)
at javax.swing.JList.setSelectionInterval(JList.java:2065)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.adjustSelection(BasicListUI.java:2739)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicListUI.java:2695)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:280)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6530)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4522)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Codigo:

```
Transaction tx = null;
DefaultListModel modeloLista = new DefaultListModel();
SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session s = sf.openSession();
private final List cancion;

public Principal() {
    initComponents();
    tx = s.beginTransaction();
    cancion = s.createQuery("FROM Cancion").list();
    for (Iterator iterator = cancion.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Cancion cancion1 = (Cancion) iterator.next();

        jList1.setModel(modeloLista);
        modeloLista.addElement(cancion1.getCancionId());
    }
    jList1.addListSelectionListener(this);
    tx.commit(); //revisar
}

private void rellenarValoresLista(int index) {
    tx = s.beginTransaction();
    Cancion cancion2 = (Cancion) cancion.get(index);
    cancion2 = (Cancion) s.get(Cancion.class, cancion2.getCancionId());
    nameText.setText(cancion2.getTitulo());

    tx.commit();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jList1 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
    nameText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
        String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

    nameText.setText("jTextField1");

    jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");

    jTextField3.setText("jTextField3");

    jTextField4.setText("jTextField4");

    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(nameText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 180, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 72, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(111, 111, 111)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 99, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(65, 65, 65)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 194, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(55, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(nameText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(85, 85, 85)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGap(73, 73, 73)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 342, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Principal().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
private javax.swing.JTextField nameText;
// End of variables declaration                   

@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
        rellenarValoresLista(jList1.getSelectedIndex());
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, revisa como exponer un [mcve]. Solo una pequeña parte del código que expones está relacionado con el problema, y no incluyes parte del código que sí está relacionado con él.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes la lista de canciones previamente cargada a partir del constructor:

```
private final List cancion;

public Principal() {
    initComponents();
    tx = s.beginTransaction();
    cancion = s.createQuery("FROM Cancion").list();
    for (Iterator iterator = cancion.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Cancion cancion1 = (Cancion) iterator.next();

        jList1.setModel(modeloLista);
        modeloLista.addElement(cancion1.getCancionId());
    }
    jList1.addListSelectionListener(this);
    tx.commit(); //revisar
}
```

Luego al invocar el siguiente método vuelves a usar la sesion de hibernate:

```
private void rellenarValoresLista(int index) {
    tx = s.beginTransaction();
    Cancion cancion2 = (Cancion) cancion.get(index);
    cancion2 = (Cancion) s.get(Cancion.class, cancion2.getCancionId());
    nameText.setText(cancion2.getTitulo());

    tx.commit();
}
```

Pero es completamente innecesario, ya tenias la canción adecuada a partir de la lista:

```
private void rellenarValoresLista(int index) {
    Cancion cancion2 = (Cancion) cancion.get(index);
    nameText.setText(cancion2.getTitulo());
}
```

Comment: Okey muchas racias ya lo conseguí :)